# Safe to solder directly onto Pi GPIO pins?

Tags: gpio, hardware, screen, pitft

I just purchased an Adafruit 2.2" PiTFT screen with the intent of fitting it inside an official Raspberry Pi case. If fits pretty well just resting directly onto the GPIO pins (without the supplied 20x2 header).
Before I commit, is it safe to solder the screen directly onto the GPIO pins?
[image: Visual aide]

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  Does it actually work just sitting on the pins like that, BTW?

Comment: @goldilocks The screen gets power but doesn't seem to clear after I've set it up via SSH (Stays white).

Comment: In that case I'd only solder on the pins you actually need until you get it working on the off chance that, you know, you can't get it working....at least that makes getting it off again easier.

Comment: Only the near end of the connector in the picture is fully plugged in. You need to press harder on the other end.

Comment: @PaulF8080 On closer inspection the HDMI port is too tall to have the screen lay completely flat. I may order a shorter GPIO header.

Comment: If you push one end all the way in, the other end is almost impossible. You alternate pushing on each end slightly until no gold shows.

Comment: If you are going to solder it on and it won't go completely down because of the HDMI port, you could shim it *up* level and solder it there.  As long as it is actually resting on the port on the other side, that should prevent excess stress on the pins when you take the shim out.

Comment: @PaulF8080 I didn't say the problem was unique to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GeneralBison it is safe. I always wanted a power on/reset switch and it was soldered in "RUN" no problems accured it was trully working